# How to enable long press gesture on table cell in xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I am working on Xamarin.iOS. I need that when I long press on a `UITableCell` of a `UITableView` a specific menu pop up in the form of `UIActionSheet`.

I have tried using the sources at Xamarin official website but I failed. 
Have anyone done this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/GrowRowTable) I managed to add a long press gesture by altering this method in `GrowRowTableCell`

```
public GrowRowTableCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    var longPressGesture = new UILongPressGestureRecognizer (LongPressMethod);
    AddGestureRecognizer (longPressGesture);
}


void LongPressMethod (UILongPressGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer)
{
    if(gestureRecognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
    {
        Console.Write("LongPress");
        var selectCategory = new UIActionSheet ("ActionSheet", null, "Cancel", "test");
        selectCategory.ShowInView (this);
    }
}
```

looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much brother. You have solved my problem.

Comment: No worries glad I could help

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.